# How can I compute the limit as $n \to\infty$ of $n^\beta/(n+1)^\beta$? (where $\beta >0$ is not an integer)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

It is well known that $\lim_{n \to\infty } \dfrac{n^{\beta}}{(n+1)^{\beta}} = 1$,  if $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$.

But what if $\beta >0$ such that $\beta$ is not necessarily a natural number?

How could I still use that limit property to calculate the limit?

Comment: Bound $\beta$ with two natural number and then apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Take any natural number $k\ge \beta.$ Then $$\left ({n\over n+1}\right )^k\le \left ({n\over n+1}\right )^\beta \le 1.$$

Comment: Or write it as $\lim_{n \to\infty } \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^{\beta}}$

Answer (score 0):

Using Bernoulli's inequality:  $1 - \beta\cdot \dfrac{1}{1+n} < \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\beta} = \left(\dfrac{n}{1+n}\right)^{\beta} < 1$. Hence the limit is $1$.